# Why integral along unit circle centred at $0$ for $z^{-2}$ is $0$, while for $z^{-1}$ is $2\pi i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we put $e^{i\theta}$, the calculation would show the results in the title.

And since $\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have a primitive along the unit circle, the integral of it is not $0$.

But for $z^{-2}$, the definition of complex exponential defines that $z^{-2}=e^{-2\log(z)}$, then we need choose a branch for $\log(z)$, and $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is not continuous along the unit circle. Then why $z^{-2}$, which involves a discontinuous $\operatorname{Log}(z)$, has a primitive along the unit circle and then the integral is $0$?

Comment: $
e^{ - 2(\log z + 2\pi ik)}  = e^{ - 2\log z- 4\pi ik}  = e^{ - 2\log z} 
$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Gary notes, raising to an integer power isn't multi-valued because$$k,\,n\in\Bbb Z\implies kn\in\Bbb Z\implies(e^{2\pi ik})^n=e^{2\pi ikn}=1,$$so $\oint_{|z|=1}z^{-1}dz\ne0$ results from the antiderivative $\ln z$ of $z^{-1}$ having multiple branches (although $z^{-1}$ doesn't). Your "analogous" argument that $\oint_{|z=1|}z^{-2}dz\ne0$ relies on spurious multiple-branches assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, and is it true that for all $z\neq0$, $z^c$, c is complex, $z^c$ is not multi-valued and continuous and holomorphic?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll No it is not true. $z^c =\exp(c\log z)$. This is single-valued precisely when $c\cdot 2\pi k i$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi i$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e., when $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive of $z^{-2}$ is $-z^{-1}$ which is continuous in an open neighborhood of the unit circle.